# How long has Victoria's ordeal been going on?

Tags: black-mirror, white-bear

In "White Bear", S2E02 of *Black Mirror*, we meet Victoria, who awakes without a memory of her previous life, being pursued by some sort of bounty hunters who seem out to kill her, while most other people keep their distance, silently watching with their phones.

In the end,

> it turns out to be her sentence for a crime she committed. She relives this day after day, in punishment for what she did. Her surroundings are an elaborate set.

**Is there any indication how long this has been going on and how long this will go on?**

In preparation for the next day, we see one of the staff crossing off the day on the calendar, so the passage of time *is* noted.

Comment: Being as the episode acts as a commentary on the "string 'em up" approach to noteworthy crimes in Britain, it makes sense thematically that this is Victoria's fate forever, until the day she dies - a "cruel and unusual" punishment taken to the nth degree. That said, I don't *think* that the episode itself provides an answer to either how long her punishment has been going on for, or how long it will go on for.

Comment: @SQB, any thoughts?

Comment: @Bebs I think Dr R Dizzle is right.

Answer (score 7):

The only thing said, is that it lasts from at least the 1st of october, and we are the 17th.
[image: Calendar]

Then, we never see her eating, and we can assume she has no time for that considering she is always rushing. However, she drinks probably every day when the session starts, that can make her survive 17 days.
[image: Glass of water]

She will likely live these sessions until she dies.

Comment: When they drive to the woods, she has a vision of the group eating. It might not be shown due to the episode limited length but this is at least one place where she eats...